# Select 'child' based on 'parent' id with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have checkboxes, each with a unique id. When a 'parent' is checked, the 'child' checkboxes should also be checked. The problem is that 'parent' checkboxes are associated with children based on the ID, not the element hierarchy since they are all at same level:

```html
<div id="checkinline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__100"></input> <- 'parent' 
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__10010"></input> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__10020"></input> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__10030"></input> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__10040"></input> 
</div>
```

When `CC__100` is checked, I need all checkboxes with ids prefixed by `CC__100` to also be checked.

My attempt so far:

```js
 $("div#" + id + " :input").each(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        var element_id = input.prop('id');
        var element_type = input.prop('type');
        if (element_type === 'checkbox') {
            if (element_id == i miss this) {
                $(this).prop('checked', true)
            }
        }

    })
```

Comment: I see no "select box"es and what's "unic"?

Comment: input with id `CC__100` isn't a parent of nothing, maybe do u want refer to it as `first element` of inputs

Comment: So you want that, when ```CC__100``` is clicked, set the values of ```CC__10010-20...``` also?

Comment: What i mean by parent has to be with the ID not the element since they are all at same level in hierarchy. <- its int he title dude

Comment: i want when i click the CC__100 all others that have CC__100 be checked to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking way to complicated, you should check if the "parent" 'changes'. When it's check state is checked then check all the elements with an id that starts with 'CC__100'.

That's the "[id^='CC__100']" part ([selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Examples)).

```js
$("#CC__100").change(function () {
  if (this.checked) {
    $("[id^='CC__100']").prop("checked", true);
  }
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/andrewRmillar/pen/mdJQLqg)

Comment: So if the OP had 100 parent checkboxes would you expect them to copy this `change` function 100 times?

Comment: this worked for me, ofcourse i had to make some changes: ````function Select_Childs(element)
{
 if (element.checked) {

     var parentid = $(element).prop('id');
    $('[id^="'+parentid+'"]').prop("checked", true);
  }
}````

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No I would not, but I would think that my example would be a nice starting point of a little learning journey for the OP. For that you would need to go to palash's answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869954/select-child-based-on-parent-id-with-jquery/60870145#60870145.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this using [attribute starts with selector [id^="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```js
$('.chk :checkbox').on('change', (e) => {
  $(e.target).nextAll('[id^="'+ e.target.id +'"]').prop('checked', e.target.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chk">
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__100" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__10010" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__10020" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__10030" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__10040" /><br/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__200" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__20010" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__20020" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__20030" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__20040" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) (`[attr^=value]`) attribute selector to find elements with an id that starts with the id of the checkbox that was just checked.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(e => {
  const { target } = e;
  
  // Children have an ID that start with the id of the select checbox, but don't have the exact id
  const children = $( `input[type=checkbox][id^=${target.id}][id!=${target.id}]` );
  
  // Set children to the value of the parent:
  children.prop( 'checked', $(target).prop('checked') );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkinline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__100"><label for="CC__100">Parent 100</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__10010"><label for="CC__10010">Child 10010</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__10020"><label for="CC__10020">Child 10020</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__10030"><label for="CC__10030">Child 10030</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__10040"><label for="CC__10040">Child 10040</label><br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__200"><label for="CC__200">Parent 200</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__20010"><label for="CC__20010">Child 20010</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__20020"><label for="CC__20020">Child 20020</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__20030"><label for="CC__20030">Child 20030</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="CC__20040"><label for="CC__20040">Child 20040</label><br>
</div>
```